# Symfony PHPUnit getLink

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have functional test. I create the entity then follow to the redirect - in action this is my list entities template, then from all entities I need selectLink for edit entity. In my template I have a link for editing the route like this:

```
{% for skill in entities %}
    <tr>
       <td>
            <a href="{{ path('admin_tim_skill_edit', { 'id': skill.id }) }}">{{ skill.id }}</a>
        </td>
        {# ... #}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I click the `admin_tim_skill_edit` route for the entity I created?

Early I have a redirect for showing one entity and have one word in the link: `Edit`. Now I have a table for all entities and links for editing each entity, and it does not work

This is my test:

```
public function testCompleteScenario()
{
    // Create a new client to browse the application
    $this->logIn();
    //$client = static::createClient();
    // Create a new entry in the database
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/admin/tim/directory/skill/');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), "Unexpected HTTP status code for GET /admin/tim/directory/skill/");
    $crawler = $this->client->click($crawler->selectLink('Add New')->link());

    // Fill in the form and submit it
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Create')->form(array(
        'artel_profilebundle_skill[skill]'  => 'Test',
        // ... other fields to fill
    ));

    $this->client->submit($form);

    $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();

    // Check data in the show view
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('td:contains("Test")')->count(), 'Missing element td:contains("Test")');

    // Early I have redirect for show one entity and have one word in link "Edit". Now I have table for all entities. And this is not work
    $crawler = $this->client->click($crawler->selectLink('Edit')->link());

    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Update')->form(array(
        'artel_profilebundle_skill[skill]'  => 'Foo',
        // ... other fields to fill
    ));

    $this->client->submit($form);
    $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();

    // Check the element contains an attribute with value equals "Foo"
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('[value="Foo"]')->count(), 'Missing element [value="Foo"]');

    // Delete the entity
    $this->client->submit($crawler->selectButton('Delete')->form());
    $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();

    // Check the entity has been delete on the list
    $this->assertRegExp('/Foo/', $this->client->getResponse()->getContent());
}
```